# javascript/html/css Show/hide box

Tags: javascript, html, toggle

I have done something like this before but this time code is not working.  Basically, I want to let users toggle a box of html on and off.  Here is a jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/2pcwW/

There are several problems with this.  First it isn't working as is possibly due to a typo.  Second, I would like the default to be hide text, not show it, the opposite of what this tries to do.  Finally, is it possible to place a table inside of the div so the whole table gets toggled on and off--in place of just "some text".

Here is non working code..same as in jsfiddle.

```
JS:
function toggleBox(obj) {
            var box = document.getElementById("box");
            if (box.style.display == "none") {
                box.style.display = "";
                obj.innerHTML = <div>Hide</div>;
            } else {
                box.style.display = "none";
                obj.innerHTML = <div>Show</div>";
            }
        }
html:
<table><tr><td><div>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="toggleBox(this);"><div>Hide</div></a><div id="box">
Some text</div></div></td></tr></table>
```

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: you should wrap  <div>Hide</div> and <div>Show</div> with "

Comment: You should use the Console: there are some syntax errors (the html in the function should be between quotes).

Comment: Also on jsFiddle, your js is wrapped in a loader function, so it isn't accessible from in-html javascript-links. On jsFiddle, on the sidebar set 'onLoad' to 'no wrap'.

Comment: Also you are trying to reference an element by its id, but the id you are trying to reference doesn't exist

Comment: Working version: http://jsfiddle.net/2pcwW/10/

Comment: Thanks!  How would I invert so default is hide?  Also can you put table tags inside the div being toggled?

Answer (score 2):

Well, if you're okay not using JavaScript (and supporting only browsers that implement the `:target` pseudo-selector):

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div>
                <a href="#box">
                    <div>Hide</div>
                </a>
                <div id="box">
                    Some text. <a href="#">Hide</a></div>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

And CSS:

```
#box {
    display: none;
}

#box:target {
    display: block;
}​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/2pcwW/5/).